# How to Print QR code to bluetooth printer

Tags: android, printing

I'm trying to print my generated QR code using bluetooth printer

This how i tried to display

```
QrCodeCreator.getBitmapFromString(name);
    mmOutputStream.write(center);
    printPhoto(R.drawable.icon);
    mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
    byte[] command = Utilss.decodeBitmap(QrCodeCreator.getBitmapFromString(name));
    mmOutputStream.write(command);
```

public class QrCodeCreator {

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromString(String qrText) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = QRCode.from(qrText).to(ImageType.PNG).withSize(300, 300).stream();

    byte[] data = out.toByteArray();
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, null);
    return bmp;
}
```

}

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: no error shows, also it is not printing on the device